# push notification inconsistencies

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

*Working scenario:* When I run my app from xcode directly to my device I can run a push notification on the server and it works just as expected.

*Non-working scenario:* I export the app to an IPA and install the app on my device via iTunes. When I push a notification from the server I'll get the error of `ERROR: Unable to send message ID 1: Invalid token (8).`

While writing this post I had a thought and checked the device id when it came from the xcode install vs the IPA install and they are different!

code for sending the device id to my server:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // You can send here, for example, an asynchronous HTTP request to your web-server to store this deviceToken remotely.

    // convert token to a single string
    NSString *token = [[[deviceToken description]
                        stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                       withString:@""];

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", token]];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsitename.com/ApnsPHP/add.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSError *e = nil;
            NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&e];
            NSLog(@"response from server: %@", dict);
        });
    }];

    NSLog(@"Did register for remote notifications: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

How can I get it so that the device token from the IPA distribution goes through? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was perusing related questions when I found [this question about push notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707150/iphone-push-notification-works-in-sandbox-but-not-in-production-mode). I thought about the idea and started checking out things from top to bottom. I finally found this:

[image: Apple Push Notification Developer View]

Hopefully the problem is as apparent to you as it was to me, but I understand if it's not. APNs will not work with an IPA unless the status for the *Production Push SSL Certificate* is `Enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode install is your development version, .ipa is production/adhoc, and they have different certificates. Read the remote notifications guide carefully!

Comment: I've already done a `release` level certificate, but if my certificate is wrong then why is my device releasing a token at all?